# Javascript includes and map together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a challenge, but is not just about the challenge it self but is more about the fact the I would like to understand how to do it.

Given an anagram `(string)`: `abba`

and an `array` of words: `['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']`

To find which one is an anagram and which not.

So I thought I can simply take the string (abba) and with `includes` and `map` throught it and just splice the false ones.

```
  const res = word.includes(
    words.map(item =>
      item.split('').map(x => {
        return x
      })
    )
  );
  console.log('res', res);
```

But I always get one false cause map just returns the array (i.e.) `'abcd'` and not (i.e.) `'a'` and the `'b'` and so on... so that makes impossible to includes() to actually look into the `string`.

How can I solve it??

Where I'm mistaking???

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct. Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with correctly spelled code

Comment: `.map()` always returns an array and `.include()` always expects a string. There is no way to use them together like you tried. You can probably do a `.map()` with `.include()` as part of the callback. However, `.map()` isn't the correct tool here - it's useful if you want to transform an array into another array. Since you want to just produce a single value, you can use `.some()`/`.every()`. `.reduce()`/`.reduceRight()` are also an option but the specialised methods are usually better when applicable.

Comment: thanks a lot. I also checked the solution but I would like to try in another way. I'll defenitely try other methods